# svg.js / svg-pan-zoom - doubleclick interactions

Tags: javascript, angularjs, svg.js, svgpanzoom

I am using Ariutta's svg-pan-zoom with svg.js. I have disabled the native Arriuta doubleclick functionality and have tried adding my own, which ultimately consists of a pan adjustment and an animation.

Usually this works fine, but sometimes when I load my page the doubleclick function acts strangely. According to my debugging, it looks like sometimes when my app loads, the doubleclick function I wrote is called twice for each doubleclick. This causes the animation to behave strangely, and there seems to be no consistent basis for when this issue arises. Restarting my server sometimes works, and sometimes doesn't. I pretty much just have to continue reloading my page until the issue goes away.

My initial thoughts are that maybe there is something off in the load order of my files, and sometimes things load out of order. Currently investigating this. My other thought was that maybe this has something to do with the svg.js animation library or my trying to replace the native double-click function in arriuta's plugin. Thoughts?

```
myApp.service('AnimatorService', function(){
   this.dblClickBehavior = function(svgCanvas, zoom){   
        $('.node').dblclick(function(){

            // get pan
            pan = zoom.getPan();

            // get screen width and height
            var sizes = zoom.getSizes();
            var centerX = (sizes.width)/2;
            var centerY = (sizes.height)/2;

            // get center position of svg object double clicked 
            var x0 = this.instance.first().attr('cx');
            var y0 = this.instance.first().attr('cy');

            //determine the correct pan value necessary to center the svg
            panAdjustX = centerX - x0*sizes.realZoom;
            panAdjustY = centerY - y0*sizes.realZoom;

            //center the svg object by adjust pan
            zoom.pan({'x' :centerX - x0*sizes.realZoom, 'y' : centerY - y0*sizes.realZoom});

            //simple animation on the object
            this.instance.first().animate().radius(centerX);

        }); 
       }
});
```

When it behaves correctly, the svg image centers and then grows. When it behaves incorrectly, it centers and then shrinks into nothingness.

Comment: Are you somehow attaching the event handler twice - some kind of initialization code getting fired twice?

Comment: No. I have attached it once only. Also, If I had attached it twice, would it not fire twice every time, rather than just sometimes?

Comment: If it always attached every time, yes. Without any code, let alone all the code, it is tough to say. It would be a total duct tape solution, but if you just want to address the sympton, you could debounce your event handler code so it ignores double-clicks that fire within x ms. You can read more about debouncing by searching, but here is the doc for lodash's [debounce](https://lodash.com/docs#debounce) which will give you an idea. Like I said, it would be a kludge, but there's really not a lot of info to go on with the question.

Comment: Thanks @barry-johnson I have uploaded some code.

Comment: Are you using angular? Probably worth tagging that in your question as well. Just too many libraries interacting here to easily reason about it through a narrow lens. You could consider setting up a plunkr for it if you want people to try to debug the code for you. You might consider reframing your question. Like I said, the quick hack is to add debouncing - wrap your handler code with a debounce function and install that debounced version as your event handler.

Comment: (I'm a svg-pan-zoom contributor).
Event if you disable dblClick from svg-pan-zoom, the library is still listening for single click (necessary for panning). But I don't see how it would interfere with your code.

Comment: You can test if your handler is set twice by setting a debug point (or console.log) right inside of `dblClickBehavior`.

Comment: @Bumbu - Man I really appreciate you answering questions on all of my threads! I tried that and indeed I find that only sometimes it seems to register twice. 

barry-johnson - I have not yet had time to come back to this piece as I got pulled into another high priority item. I will come back to this later this week though and play with your suggestion. Will post my progress at that time. Thanks to you both for your help!

Comment: @barry-johnson - So I have tried a few different debounce libraries, the first two (underscore and lodash) seemed to cause some kind of conflict with the version of jquery I was using, so I found an angular specific version (shahata's angular-debounce) which seemed to be compatible and execute properly. The strange thing is, that it doesn't seem to fix the issue even as a bandage fix. Am going to dive into this further and see what I can uncover.

Answer (score 0):

You tagged svg.js so I will give an svg.js answer. There is a plugin svg.panZoom.js now which can be used to easily implement the functionality you want:

```
var canvas = SVG('container').viewbox(0,0,1000,1000)

canvas.image('https://www.zooroyal.de/magazin/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/cat-2783601_1920.jpg', 1000, 1000)
  .attr('preserveAspectRatio', 'none')

canvas.on('dblclick', function(e) {
  var p = this.point(e.pageX, e.pageY)
  var zoomLvl = 3

  // zoom into point p to zoomLvl
  canvas.animate().zoom(zoomLvl, p)
})
```

Here is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Fuzzy/95t6oL8y/5/

When you want to be able to panZoom your svg, too. Just add a call to `canvas.panZoom()`